# Google authentication failed using firebase react hook

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

Getting the below error while Google signup/signin using firebase react hook

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you use auth to check if the user signed in in App.js

```
import { auth } from '../firebase/config';
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth';

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          //user auth object here
        } else {
          signOut(auth)
        }
    }
  }, [])


  eg:
  return (
    <>
      {user && <Profile/>}//assuming user is a state [user, setUser]
      <Homepage/>
    </>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect depending on user state or do something, you have to do it inside useEffect hook .

Example:

useEffect(() => {
if (user) {
(Do whatever you want to)
}
}, [user]);